# Maven direct and transitive dependencies resolution

Tags: maven

Artifact_A has both the direct dependency and the transitive dependency on Artifact_B within the same scope.

Does the `direct dependency` always precede the `transitive dependency`, or the one of `higher version` prevail?

Is there any reference with better illustration on `Maven Dependencies Resolution` than the chapter [Maven reference manual - Project Dependencies](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-dependencies.html)?

Comment: What do you mean by prevail? Could you make an actual example or show your pom.xml and dependencies?

Answer (score 3):

The dependency-resolution mechanism can be complicated. If there's a managed version (`dependencyManagement`), then that will take precedence. Generally speaking, Maven will use the highest-requested version that satisfies all of the requirements (for example, some servlet package might require `[2.4,3.0)` while another package requires `2.5`, so Maven will use 2.5). If Maven can't find such a version (in the above sample, if the second package required `[3.0,4.0)`), then it will produce an error.

If you have a specific issue that you're running into, feel free to post a question with all the details.